# Present participles in a noun phrase

Tags: theoretical-linguistics, formal-semantics, meaning, cognitive-linguistics

I'm working on a research project on premodufying present participles and I would like to have a native speaker's impression on the grammaticality or frequency of the following options.
There are three boys, one of them is jumping.
Would you say:
a. The boy jumping is my nighbour.
b. The jumping boy is my neighbour.
c. The boy who is jumping is my neighbour.
d. The boy jumping over there is my neighbour.
(A similar exampke being dealt with by Meltzer, 2007)

Comment: To me all four are grammatical but (a) is very marked and (b) is a bit marked.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. Would you say (a ) sounds even odd?

Comment: How fast is he jumping? What are the other kids doing? How old is he? Who am I talking to? They all affect my speech. And _jumping_ is an unlikely word for me to use except in certain contexts.